# Can't get all nav elements from the webpage using Scrapingbee

Tags: python, web-scraping

I tried to scraped the data from this url:[https://www.airbnb.ca/s/Coeur-d'Alene--Idaho--United-States/homes?tab_id=home_tab&refinement_paths%5B%5D=%2Fhomes&flexible_trip_lengths%5B%5D=one_week&monthly_start_date=2023-06-01&monthly_length=3&price_filter_input_type=0&price_filter_num_nights=5&channel=EXPLORE&query=Coeur%20d%27Alene%2C%20ID&place_id=ChIJj3xVuvi0YVMRkFK_BVuZ5V8&date_picker_type=calendar&source=structured_search_input_header&search_type=autocomplete_click&locale=en&_set_bev_on_new_domain=1684253805_ZGNjZjFhOGE4ZGRk](https://www.airbnb.ca/s/Coeur-d%27Alene--Idaho--United-States/homes?tab_id=home_tab&refinement_paths%5B%5D=%2Fhomes&flexible_trip_lengths%5B%5D=one_week&monthly_start_date=2023-06-01&monthly_length=3&price_filter_input_type=0&price_filter_num_nights=5&channel=EXPLORE&query=Coeur%20d%27Alene%2C%20ID&place_id=ChIJj3xVuvi0YVMRkFK_BVuZ5V8&date_picker_type=calendar&source=structured_search_input_header&search_type=autocomplete_click&locale=en&_set_bev_on_new_domain=1684253805_ZGNjZjFhOGE4ZGRk)

While I was trying to get all nav elements, I expected there should be two nav elements as I can see in the inspection of the website. But it showed me only one.
I actually wanted the one with 'aria-label' set to 'Search results navigation' but didn't get it.

I enabled javascript rendering with 'render_js':'True' option. Please help me how I can solve this.

```
from scrapingbee import ScrapingBeeClient
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

client = ScrapingBeeClient(
    api_key="MY_API_KEY"
)

params = {'render_js': 'True'}

response = client.get(
    "https://www.airbnb.ca/s/Coeur-d'Alene--Idaho--United-States/homes?tab_id=home_tab&refinement_paths%5B%5D=%2Fhomes&flexible_trip_lengths%5B%5D=one_week&monthly_start_date=2023-06-01&monthly_length=3&price_filter_input_type=0&price_filter_num_nights=5&channel=EXPLORE&query=Coeur%20d%27Alene%2C%20ID&place_id=ChIJj3xVuvi0YVMRkFK_BVuZ5V8&date_picker_type=calendar&source=structured_search_input_header&search_type=autocomplete_click&locale=en&_set_bev_on_new_domain=1684253805_ZGNjZjFhOGE4ZGRk",
    params=params,
)



if response.status_code == 200:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

    navs = soup('nav')
    print(navs)

else: print("False")
```

Expected two nav elements but got only one.